# Attiny85: how to rotate the servo continuously with a press of a button?

Tags: programming, servo, attiny85

I'm trying to use two Bluetooth commands in my code:
one is press off a button "1" the servo should do its routine without stop
second one press of the a button "2" servo should stop.

What am I getting with my code is button 1 pressed servo is executing the routine only once and then I need to press again. But I want the routine to loop until I'll stop it.

I'm adding here the code:

```
  #include <SoftSerial.h>     
#include <TinyPinChange.h>  
#include <SoftRcPulseOut.h> 
#define SERVO_PIN         0

#define REFRESH_PERIOD_MS 4

#define NOW               1

int pos = 0;  

SoftRcPulseOut myservo; 

SoftSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX
void setup()  
{
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN); 


}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  char c = mySerial.read();
  if(c == '1')  selfservo();
  if (c == '2') selfservo2();
}
```

ok the selfservo() is:

```
void selfservo() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(REFRESH_PERIOD_MS);        // waits 20ms for refresh period 
    SoftRcPulseOut::refresh(NOW);    // generates the servo pulse Now
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(REFRESH_PERIOD_MS);        // waits 20ms for for refresh period 
    SoftRcPulseOut::refresh(NOW);    // generates the servo pulse Now
  } 
}
```

and selfservo2() is:

```
void selfservo2() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 

  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                

  } 
}
```

Comment: look at your code ... it says `if the button IS pressed then move the servo` .... change it to `if the button WAS pressed then move the servo` ... you do that by "remembering" if the button was pressed

Comment: @jsotola tell me more please! how should it look like?

Comment: separate the `receive data` function from the `act on the data` function  .... define a `flag` variable such as `bool move;` ... the received data makes the `move` variable `true` or `false` ... do this at the beginning of the `loop()` block .... later in the loop() block, perform actions depending on the value of `move`, not on the value of received data ...... it is basically a simple state machine with two states

Comment: That's precisely how I would have described it: you need a variable that indicates whether or not the servo should be rotating, toggled by the button(s). (Two buttons seems overkill, but there may be a specific UX need for this.)